# Compare values in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, comparison, vba

I am trying to compare cell A1 with B1 and if it is true populate cell F1 with the A1 value. But irrespective of my input values the if condition becomes true.

```
Sub Macro3()
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
    For i = 1 To 10
        If (Range("A" & i).Select = Range("B" & i).Select) Then
            Range("A" & i).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Range("F" & i).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
        End If
    Next i      
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you running the code with the sheet you want to adapt as the active worksheet? What values lie in A1 and B1 that aren't the same yet trigger the True condition? Why not a simple IF test? :)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of selecting, copying, and pasting, you can compare the Value property of the cells, then set the F column Value accordingly:

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 10
    If Range("A" & i).Value = Range("B" & i).Value Then
        Range("F" & i).Value = Range("A" & i).Value
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for a very useful suggestion..
main problem i have is "If Range("A" & i).Value = Range("B" & i).Value " this condition fails irrespective of the values in A and B column

Comment: @Venkat - Are you saying there's no match even when the values are the same? Something is not what you think it is...

Comment: @tim williams:- yes that was the case previously....But that works fine now...that problem is resolved...i have completed the code..Now the problem is with the PERFORMANCE
I use 2 sheets to perform the task.  Here  I compare each row of excel 1 with all the active rows of excel 2. so i am getting caught in the for loop...excel crashes as the count of row is high. Whether i can get any suggestions to improve the performance

Answer (score 0):

Consider this a compliment to Nick's answer (accept his if you find it to work, which you should). I wanted to help explain some of the things that are wrong in your code.

***Before FIX:***

```
Sub Macro3()
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
    For i = 1 To 10
        If (Range("A" & i).Select = Range("B" & i).Select) Then
            Range("A" & i).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Range("F" & i).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

***AFTER FIX***

```
Sub Macro4()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 10
        If Range("A" & i).Value = Range("B" & i).Value Then
            Range("F" & i).Value = Range("A" & i).Value
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

***POINTS:***

1. Use Long instead of Integer (small optimization since VBA will convert the int to a long anyway)
2. No need to declare i = 1 twice in a row
3. You should be comparing values, not simply selecting cells. There is rarely, if ever, a need to use the .Select keyword. You can access all object's properties directly.
4. Copy and paste is a heavy operation. Since you are in VBA, may as well just assign the value that is in A to the cell in column B. It's faster, and more effecient.

I hope this helps. BTW, you can simple enter:

```
=IF(A1=B1,A1,"")
```

in F1 and drag the formula down to get a similar result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variant array to address your performance issue that you raise above. This code will run the same as Nicks except it will skip blanks cell, ie it will

1. update the F value if A and B are the same
2. skip updates if the A cell is blank
3. leave the existing F values in place if A<>B

It wasn't clear to me how you are comparing rows accross two sheets, can you expand on this?

```
    Sub MyArray()
    Dim X As Variant
    Dim Y As Variant
    Dim lngrow As Long
    X = Range([a1], Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
    Y = Range([f1], [f1].Offset(UBound(X, 1) - 1, 0))
    For lngrow = 1 To UBound(X, 1)
       If Len(X(lngrow, 1)) > 0 Then
       If X(lngrow, 1) = X(lngrow, 2) Then Y(lngrow, 1) = X(lngrow, 1)
       End If
    Next
    Range([f1], [f1].Offset(UBound(X, 1) - 1, 0)) = Y
    End Sub
```