# Comparing Data in 4 Columns

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I am new to VB I need to compare the address on both columns.

If both addresses match check whether both data match, if not output both source file and dump file address and data to a text file.

If an address in column A is not found in column C, output source file address and data to a text file.

If an address in column C is not found in column A, output dump file address and data to a text file.

Hope someone can help me. Thanks!

```
  Source File           Dump File  
      a         b          c        d
1  address    data      address    data
2   s100       a         s010       x
3   S010       x         s020       b
4   S030       y         S030       y
5   s040       z         S040       d
```

---

One Issue

If the addresses match, I think it doesnt check whether the data is the same at both the addresses. For example, source file has address 's040' with data 'z' but dump file has address 's040' with data 'd'

Time Issue

It took very long as there are ard 900M iterations. Is it better to to remove the duplicates first then run this search? I tried to use excel's remove duplicates feature but it only work for one column. It takes ard 25mins for the whole cycle.

---

Combining Data if Consecutive addresses are unique in a list:

If there is a chunk of unique addresses in one column, I need to find the start address of the first unique address and the last unique address and 
output only those lines which are not all FF's like this:

```
'If all the data are FF's output like this
File: dump.s19
0x006180 – 0x007E8F
[Result] OK

'Here certain lines are all FF's which are not displayed here, only Non FF's lines need to printed as follows.
File: dump.s19
0x007EB0 – 0x00FFFF
S224007FF0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF4247494EFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0000FFFF66
S224008010FFFFFFFF01019D160825A100100201FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFCA

S224008050302D4100E0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFA8
S224008070FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFA3BF454E442EFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF9E
Result: NOK
```

---

I am not sure how to integrate this additional logic into my code.

```
'Set the address you're trying to find
            fa = Range(sf & cr).Value
            fa_data = Range(Chr(Asc(sf) + 1) & cr).Value
            Debug.Print "fa" & fa
'Find it
            Set targetcell = Range(si & 3 & ":" & si & lr_2).Find(What:=fa, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True)
'If Nothing is returned it is not found
            If targetcell Is Nothing Then
'Write your search cell and it's ajacent to your file.
                If l = 1 Then

                    startadd = Range(sf & cr).Value
                    If startadd <> "FFFFFF" Then

                        Dec_startadd = Val("&H" & startadd & "&H")
                        lgth = Len(Range(Chr(Asc(sf) + 1) & cr)) - 2
                        lgth = lgth / 2 - 1
                        endadd = Hex(Dec_startadd + lgth)
                        endadd = Right("000000" & endadd, 6)

                        Print #fn, "File:" & orig_filename
                        Print #fn, "0x" & startadd & " - 0x" & endadd
                        Print #fn, Range(Chr(Asc(sf) - 1) & cr).Value & Range(sf & cr).Value & Range(Chr(Asc(sf) + 1) & cr).Value
                        Print #fn, "Result: NOK"
                        Print #fn,
                        Print #fn,
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, what have you tried so far? SO is not a code writing service, please provide what you have tried to solve this yourself.

Comment: in less than 1 minute http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899034/compare-values-in-excel-vba and http://www.homeandlearn.org/write_to_a_text_file.html

Comment: I planned to use two for loop. Since there are more addresses in dump file (35000) and ard 31000 files in address i am not sure how to do it efficiently.  I have not done a lot of coding and I am a beginner so it is seems very complicated for me.

Comment: Show what you have tried and/or get stuck with, this shows research and effort. just asking without providing = plz give me the codez.

Comment: Where are you getting the data from? It may be quicker, for instance, if you use a database's own functionality rather than trying to process 132,000 cells in Excel.

Comment: I am getting the data from 2 .s19 files.  I am not sure if it has any database functionality.

Comment: I import the 2 .s19 files into excel and then split them into the 2columns address and data. Is it a better idea keep it as a single string ? Because after the search I need to check if the data cell if all the characters are FFFFF, if it's true return OK if not return NOT OK.

Comment: @JasonStallard Will Microsoft Access or SQL Server Express be a better software to do this task?

Comment: Doesn't Metrowerks use s19 files? I'm just a beginner myself in VBA; I'm not a business analyst or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I whipped this up for the fun of it:

```
'Get a the next available file number
    fn = FreeFile
'Open your file ready for writing.
    Open "your full path and file name" For Output As #fn
'Set the First row to search from.
    fr = 2
'Find the last row.
    lr = ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
'Set the column for the value that you are searching for.
    sf = "A"
'Set the column for that you are searching in.
    si = "C"
'You want to search two columns
    For l = 1 To 2
'Loop from first row to the last row.
        For cr = fr To lr
'Set the address you're trying to find
            fa = Range(sf & cr).Value
'Find it
            Set targetcell = Range(si & fr & ":" & si & lr).Find(What:=fa, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
'If Nothing is returned it is not found
            If targetcell Is Nothing Then
'Write your search cell and it's ajacent to your file.
                Write #fn, Range(sf & cr).Value & "," & Range(Chr(Asc(sf) + 1) & cr).Value
            End If
'I always put a DoEvents in a loop; just in case you need to break out of it.
            DoEvents
        Next
'Now you've done one column swap them over and do it again.
        sf = "C"
        si = "A"
    Next
'It's done.
    Close #fn
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jason Stallard. And the comments really helped me to understand easily.

Comment: If the addresses match, I think it doesnt check whether the data is the same at both the addresses. For example, source file has address 's040' with data 'z' but dump file has address 's040' with data 'd'

Comment: You have the targetcell. You just need to compare it's .Value with the address you are finding (fa).

Comment: I agree. But we are not storing the cell value og column C anywhere, right ? I am not sure how to call the data beside it? I tried to find it  using if Range (d & cr) = range (b & cr) but it didn't work as the target cell in the  dump file could in another line than cr. I can post my code once I get home.

Comment: i mean i need to compare the data linked to the address at column b and d. target cell checks only address, right?

Comment: The following can be inserted as part of the if:
`Else
        If Range(Chr(Asc(sf) + 1) & cr).Value <> Range(Chr(targetcell.Column + 65) & cr).Value Then
            Write #fn, "Cell " & sf & cr & ": " & Range(sf & cr).Value & "," & Range(Chr(Asc(sf) + 1) & cr).Value & " differs from cell " & si & cr & ": " & Range(si & cr).Value & "," & Range(Chr(Asc(si) + 1) & cr).Value
        End If`
but it will report the differences twice. You'll need to change the loop.

Comment: I have 1 more requirement. Hope u could help me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry, @Manick9, you lost me.

Comment: Its ok. Will using a Collection or Dictionary improve the time of the program? Or is it better to switch to another language such as C# ?